# ASCII printing color codes keeps the color

Tags: colors, lua, ascii, ansi-escape

When I use:

```
print('\27[31mReady!')
```

Everything else I print keeps the same color.
And putting **\n** after it doesn't do anything. What should this even do?
Is there a "\" command to turn back close color codes like this   or not?

How do I make the text normal, so everything else I print?
I want **to make** "Ready!" red and everything **else back to normal** with the **easiest tactic (whatever)** and maybe if I add another print where it says it should be green then I want that it is green just **after the message it should be back to normal**.

Comment: `print('\27[31mReady!\27[39m\n')`  30-37 - set color, 39 - restore default color, 0 - reset all settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are finished using the new color, use `\27[0m` to reset your colors to the default.

Example:

```
print('\27[31mReady!\27[0m\n')
```

Comment: Is that the only way?

Comment: I'm not sure that it's the only way, but it's certainly the preferred way. Newlines (`\n`) doesn't have any effect on color. Use it wherever you want to add a newline. E.g.:

    print('\27[31mReady!\27[0m\n')

Comment: Where I find more \ commands?
Am I supposed to use \n like because if I print something else it makes a new line automatically.

Comment: Only use `\n` if you would otherwise, colors don't affect it. If you get a newline automatically, and you don't need another, don't use `\n`. Google for ANSI colors in terminals, there are a bunch of Lua modules that take care of that. Example: https://github.com/kikito/ansicolors.lua

Answer (score 2):

When you use

```
print('\27[31mReady!')
```

that changes the *foreground* color.  It is one of the standard ECMA-48 control sequences.  Most (not all) of the terminals you might use implement the standard SGR 39 as well (reset the foreground color).

```
print('\27[39mNext!')
```

Likewise most reset colors (and all other video attributes) on SGR 0 (zero is optional):

```
print('\27[0mDone!')
print('\27[mDone!')
```

Reference:

- [ECMA-48: Control Functions for Coded Character Sets](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm)